# Inverting order of multiple values in Common Lisp

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I've been thinking about the following problem. Suppose I'm dealing with a function returning multiple values, such as `truncate`. Is there a clever way to reverse the order of values that get returned? I'm talking about something more clever than e.g.

```
(multiple-value-bind (div rem) (truncate x y)
  (values rem div))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how clever this is, but here's what you want:

```
(reverse (multiple-value-list (the-function-that-returns-multiple-values)))
```

[multiple-value-list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_mult_1.htm) being the key, here.

To return these again as separate values, use [values-list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_vals_l.htm#values-list):

```
(values-list (reverse (multiple-value-list (the-function-that-returns-multiple-values))))
```

[This whole page](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node94.html) may be enlightening.

Comment: Yup, actually that's what I came up with in the meantime, only dressed as a macro: 

    (defmacro reverse-values (sexp)
      `(apply #'values (reverse (multiple-value-list ,sexp))))

Comment: To clarify, Tim, I meant something that would reverse the values *and* return them as separate Lisp return values. But you gave the essence, so I've marked that as answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've modified the answer with a better construct to do what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I like that better than explicitly applying `#'values`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved more cleverly by writing a higher order function whose input is a function that returns some `(values a b)`, and which returns a function which calls that function, but returns `(values b a)`. In other words a value reversing combinator:

```
(defun val-rev (function)
  (lambda (&rest args)
    (multiple-value-bind (a b) (apply function args)
       (values b a))))
```

Though inside the definition of this function we are doing the cumbersome thing you don't want (capturing the values with `m-v-bind` and reversing with `values`) this is encapsulated in the combinator and just an implementation detail. It's probably more efficient than consing up a value list and reversing it. Also, it specifically targets the first two values. If a function returns four values, `A B C D`, then reversing the `multiple-value-list` means that the first two return values will be `C D`.  However, if we just bind the first two and reverse them, then we bet `B A`. Reversing the first two (or only two) values is clearly not the same as reversing all values.

Demo:

```
[1]> (truncate 17 3)
5 ;
2
[2]> (funcall (val-rev #'truncate) 17 3)
2 ;
5
```

Note that in a Lisp-1 dialect, the invocation loses the added noise of `#'` and `funcall`, reducing simply to: `((val-rev truncate) 17 3)`.

`val-rev` is kind of a dual of the `flip` higher order function which you see in some functional languages, which takes a binary function and returns a binary function which is that function, but with the arguments reversed.

Answer (score 0):

To have it as clean/consistent as multiple-value-bind, you could define a macro such as this:

```
(defmacro reverse-multiple-value-bind (args f &rest body) 
  `(multiple-value-bind ,(reverse args) 
      ,f 
      ,@body))
```

Then you have

```
>> (multiple-value-bind (x y) (floor 3.7) (print x) (print y))
3 
0.70000005
```

and

```
> (reverse-multiple-value-bind (x y) (floor 3.7) (print x) (print y))
0.70000005 
3
```

Comment: Well, this isn't very useful, given that I already have `multiple-value-bind` and in your macro I would still need to explicitly do something with the bound values, so why bother. My question was *specifically* about returning multiple values in a reversed order, not about binding them in a reversed order.